# This is giving me the ole Cannot insert the value NULL into column error and I dont know a way around this one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
// Create the scoresheet
Scoresheet scoresheet = new Scoresheet();
scoresheet.tsakID = task.ID;

// Query Items to retrieve a list of tasks. Then create a scoresheet 
// for each item retrieved and bind them together as foreign keys.
var Items = (from c in db.Items
             where c.ID == task.ID
             select c).ToList();

// Save scoresheet item to db
scoresheet.ScoresheetItems = new List<ScoresheetItem>();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(scoresheet.ScoresheetID);

for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count(); i++)
{
    ScoresheetItem scoresheetItem = new ScoresheetItem();
    scoresheetItem.ScoresheetID = scoresheet.ScoresheetID;
    scoresheet.ScoresheetItems.Add(scoresheetItem);
}
db.Scoresheets.Add(scoresheet);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The error is on the line where I am doing `scoresheetItem.ScoresheetID = scorehseet.ScoresheetID`

The problem is that scoresheet.ScoresheetID is null until it is created. when it is created on the database, the value is assigned as an auto-incrementing value.

How do I get around this so that scoresheet.ScoresheetID is not null so that I can assign it to the scoresheetItem?

Here is the scoresheet model:

```
public class Scoresheet
{
    public int ScoresheetID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ScoresheetItem> ScoresheetItems { get; set; }
}

public class ScoresheetItem
{
    public int ScoresheetItemID { get; set; }
    public int ScoresheetItemScore { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ScoresheetID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What? How do you mean?

Comment: if your `ScoresheetID` column in the database is declared as integer, primary key, autoincrement, not-null, this should not be happening.

Comment: Guids: you can generate IDs in the client, server, or wherever. They're guaranteed to be unique so you don't have these sorts if issues.

Comment: ahh. So can i just use the [Key] tag? or do i need to use public Guid ScoresheetID ?

Comment: I updated it with my model

Comment: If you're trying to model a Foreign Key relationship, you shouldn't be setting the `ScoresheetID` manually. I'm not entirely familiar with the current versions of EF, but most ORMs take care of setting FK Ids during the insert, as long as child elements are added to the related collection.

Answer (score 1):

If ScoresheetID is an identity column then you should not be setting it in code at all when creating it. On your object you need to let EF know that is an identity column as well.  If this is code first, which I'm assuming, you can either use data annotations

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx

or fluent api to configure and map properties

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx

When creating child ScoresheetItem(s) you should not set the ScoresheetID either, your models should be configured for the relationship.

Here is one with modeling relationships and navigation properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I added my model to my question and it is the same as what they are doing in the example. How does the answer solve the problem? Because I need the ID before it is saved to the server.

Comment: if its autoi ncremented on the database you do not need the ID before it is saved to the server

Comment: I do need the id though because the foreign key for schoresheetItem to link to scoresheet. The line that I listed that is giving me the issue is where I am setting a foreign key.

Comment: Your example does not have any data annotations or fluent api code it is not the same as the example. Think you need to do a little more research with those links I provided to learn how to model your entities with keys and relationships.

Comment: Hmm...I am not following what is going on if that is the case. I can create the item in the database just fine then retrieve it, then save  the second item to the database with the foreign key no problem. the only problem that i am having is saving them both at the same time in the controller.

Comment: ahhh I figured it out... I had another part in my code where I actually did it without realizing.\

Comment: When your creating the item the first time you are setting ScoresheetID in code? If thats the case it is not auto incremented on the database

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does auto increment the primary keys in the database, but with this code above, I am trying to set a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was actually a pretty simple fault.

There is actually no need at all to set the foreign key such as I was doing right here: `scoresheetItem.ScoresheetID = scorehseet.ScoresheetID`

When I call `scoresheet.ScoresheetItems.Add(scoresheetItem);` in the code, it actually handles the foreign key for me.